# Passing a Java object to C++ via JNI and then back to Java, via void*

Tags: java, android, c++, react-native, java-native-interface

I have an Android app that employs both React Native and JNI. C++ (via a fork of the JUCE library) is used to generate one of the views.

React Native requires that a new instance of a view be returned from the overridden method `createViewInstance(context)`. This seems to get called each time a React Native component containing this view is updated.

Here is my (simplified) implementation:

```
protected JuceViewHolder createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext themedReactContext) {
    JuceBridge juceBridge = JuceBridge.getInstance();
    juceViewHolder = new JuceViewHolder(themedReactContext);

    // JNI method: this will trigger JuceBridge.createNewView
    MainActivity.createJuceWindow(juceViewHolder); 

    return juceViewHolder;
```

}

For reference, `createJuceWindow` is defined as:

```
JUCE_JNI_CALLBACK (JUCE_ANDROID_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME, createJuceWindow, jobject, (JNIEnv* env, jclass, jobject view))
{
    JuceView::getInstance().createJuceWindow(view);
}
```

which calls:

```
void createJuceWindow(jobject view)
{
    viewToAttachTo = GlobalRef(view); // [GlobalRef][1] manages NewGlobalRef
    myComponent = std::unique_ptr<MyComponent> (new MyComponent);
    myComponent->setVisible (true);
    myComponent->setOpaque(true);

    if (viewToAttachTo.get() == nullptr)
        DBG ("createJuceWindow: viewToAttachTo null!!!");

    myComponent->setBounds(Desktop::getInstance().getDisplays().getMainDisplay().userArea);
    myComponent->addToDesktop (0, viewToAttachTo.get()); // This passes in the `jobject` held by GlobalRef
}
```

I have separated the [`JuceViewHolder`](https://github.com/adamski/JUCE/blob/android-bridge-attachWindow/modules/juce_core/native/java/JuceViewHolder.java) derived from ViewGroup, and I am passing it to a C++ function via JNI in order to attach the (Java)[`ComponentPeerView`](https://github.com/adamski/JUCE/blob/android-bridge-attachWindow/modules/juce_core/native/java/JuceBridge.java#L385) generated from the (C++) [`AndroidComponentPeer`](https://github.com/adamski/JUCE/blob/android-bridge-attachWindow/modules/juce_gui_basics/native/juce_android_Windowing.cpp#L131) constructor

```
AndroidComponentPeer (Component& comp, const int windowStyleFlags, void* viewToAttachTo)
    : ComponentPeer (comp, windowStyleFlags),
      usingAndroidGraphics (false),
      fullScreen (false),
      sizeAllocated (0),
      scale ((float) Desktop::getInstance().getDisplays().getMainDisplay().scale)
{
    // NB: must not put this in the initialiser list, as it invokes a callback,
    // which will fail if the peer is only half-constructed.

    if (viewToAttachTo == nullptr) DBG ("viewToAttachTo null");
    view = GlobalRef (android.bridge.callObjectMethod (JuceBridge.createNewView,
                                                      (jboolean) component.isOpaque(),
                                                      (jlong) this,
                                                      (jobject) viewToAttachTo));

    if (view.get() == nullptr)
        DBG ("view null!");
    else
        DBG ("got view.");

    if (isFocused())
        handleFocusGain();
}
```

via the `createNewView` method: (simplified here)

```
public final ComponentPeerView createNewView (boolean opaque, long host, ViewGroup viewToAttachTo)
{
    ComponentPeerView v = new ComponentPeerView (viewToAttachTo.getContext(), opaque, host);
    viewToAttachTo.addView(v);
    return v;
}
```

`host` is a pointer to the C++ `AndroidComponentPeer` instance.

This works initially, however it seems that if I switch to another View or Activity and/or switch back to the C++ View, I get a crash similar to the following:

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted global reference 0x100566
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted global reference 0x100566
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void com.juce.JuceBridge$ComponentPeerView.focusChanged(long, boolean)
```

My current assumption is that the error is due to the `void*` pointer becoming obsolete at some point due to the garbage collector moving the underlying object, as described in [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html). What I got from the article is that `jobject` should be used in place of a pointer.

However the method signature of the `Component::addToDesktop` method that I have employed uses `void*`:

```
virtual void addToDesktop (int windowStyleFlags,
                               void* nativeWindowToAttachTo = nullptr);
```

(This is the method used in iOS to pass a native `UIView` to attach a `Component` to)

Is my assumption valid? If so, is it possible to safely cast a `void*` pointer to a Java object, store it as a `jobject` (via NewGlobalRef) and then pass it back to Java?

Comment: Fantastic question, but I suspect you will have to try it to find out.

Comment: It seems to me like you've implictly deleted some global reference too soon, by destructing a `GlobalRef` object (or some other object that somewhere further down the hierarchy owns a `GlobalRef`). Note that you might have a problem with `viewToAttachTo = GlobalRef(view);` if you ever call `createJuceWindow` more than once for the same activity, unless `GlobalRef` handles deleting the global reference it manages in its assignment operator.

Comment: Do you have the source for GlobalRef()?
There should be no problem going between void* and jobject, if they are the same size.